# Get variable value in Symfony2 FormBuilder

Tags: forms, symfony, themes, twig

I am building a form in Symfony2 and for some rows I want to pass a formatted version of each widget's value as a `title` attribute which I can then display in another `div`. 
If I have not set a formatted version, I will just insert the actual, non-formatted value into the `div` instead.

Ideally, my twig code might look like this:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}

  <div class="field-display-value">
    {% if attr['title'] is defined %}
      {{ attr['title'] }}
    {% else %}
      {{ form.vars.value }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <div class="field-widget">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
  </div>

{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

But I don't know how I can access the value of the widget in the formBuilder. Ideally I would like something like this:

```
$builder->add('some_field', 'text', array(
  'attr' => array('title' => someFormattingFunction( this.widget.value ),
));
```

Obviously, `this.widget.value` pseudocode doesn't work.

Don't know if even possible, but I don't want to have to resort to javascript madness.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should use [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this documentation :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

You have to set a listener for the PRE_SET_DATA event, on your formBuilder.
Then you will be able to access the data passed to this form with :

```
$data = $event->getData();
```

Now you juste have to add your fields inside.
/!\ Your fields will only be added, if an object is passed to the form.
So if you still want the fields when there is no data passed, you have to add the fields outside the event lister function, and then modify the fields attribute title inside this function.

```
$form = $event->getForm();
$form->add('some_field', 'text', array(
    'attr' => array('title' => someFormattingFunction($data.getSomething()),
));
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks @zapcost.
However, I ended up passing the entity data to the FormType as an option and retrieving the data directly. That way I could be more specific and avoid issues that arised when the form was submitted with errors.